# Не срабатывают CSS-тригеры изменения цвета

Tags: css3, html5

Есть список в виде меню:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">fond</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">blago</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">knigi</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

И каскадная таблица:

```
<style>
    ul {
        margin-top:20px;
        list-style:none;
    }
    li {
        float:left;
        width:80px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        background:#6495ED;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:1px;
        border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
    }
    ul li a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:black;
        font-size:19px;
    }
    ul li:hover {
        margin-top:-20px;
        height:50px;
        line-height:50px;
        background:#000080;
        color:red;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
        color:red;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
```

При наведении на пункт меню, цвет текста должен быть красным, но он почему-то так и остаётся чёрным. Становится красным только при наведении на ссылку, а мне надо, чтоб текст становился красным, даже когда курсор не касается ссылки.

Подскажите, что сделать?

Comment: @Рома Прогер, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: А у вас случайно так происходит не в IE<8? В IE<8 псевдокласс :hover нормально реагирут только на тег <a/>

Comment: нет это в хроме я ща работаю

Comment: и что за кнопка 101010?

Comment: А решение на JavaScript вас устроит?

Comment: попробывать можно

Comment: P.S. @Рома Прогер :hover :active :link и т.д. это не "тригеры" а псевдоклассы.
Тригер это часть схемы микропроцессора и регистр тоже :)

Comment: На будущее - юзайте jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение с помошью JavaScript (работает во всех браузерах):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Сила JavaScript и DOM</title>
<style>
ul.menu{
   background-color: #00FF00;
}
ul li a{
   color: #000000;
}
ul li a.lihover{
   color: #FF0000;
}
</style>
<script>
function getElementsByClassName(where, className){ //Функция работает во всех 
                //браузерах а document.getElementsByClassName везде кроме IE<9
   var allElements = where.getElementsByTagName("*"); //Получаем все тэги
   var elements = [];
   for(var i=0;i<allElements.length;i++){
      if(allElements[i].className==className){ // Отсеиваем по className
         elements.push(allElements[i]);
      }
   }
return elements; // Возвращяем результат
}
function mover(evt){ // Функция когда мышь в пределах li
   liobj=window.event ? window.event.srcElement : evt.target; //Получаем обьект на 
   //который направили мышь предположительно li
   if(liobj.tagName=="LI"){ // Если дейстаительно это li то
      obj=liobj.firstChild; // За обьект принимаем первого ребёнка li (у нас это a)
      obj.className = "lihover"; // Присваеваем обьекту новый класс
   }
}
function mout(evt){ // Функция когда мышь за пределами li
   liobj=window.event ? window.event.srcElement : evt.target; // Тоже самое
   if(liobj.tagName=="LI"){
   obj=liobj.firstChild;
   obj.className = ""; //Присваиваем обьекту класс по умолчанию
   }
}
window.onload=function(){ //После загрузки страницы
   var elements; //Получаем все тэги с классом menu
   if(document.getElementsByClassName){ // Проверяем не IE<9 ли это?
      elements = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
   }
   else{
      elements = getElementsByClassName(document, "menu");
   } 
   for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){ // Каждому присваиваем события
      elements[i].onmouseover=mover; // onMouseOver
      elements[i].onmouseout=mout; // и onMouseOut
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">fond</a></li>
<li><a href="#">blago</a></li>
<li><a href="#">knigi</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

***UPD***:

[[@Рома прогер](/users/4716/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80)](/users/4716/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80) вы были правы, я всё протестировал и узнал что: цвет `a:hover` внутри `<li/>` не меняет `color` `<a/>` а меняет `color` у `<li/>` эта новая для меня особенность `CSS` спасибо что открыли её для меня :)

P.S: лучшая альтернатива предложена [@Котик](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)'ом: ": [Функции для поиска элементов по классам и тегам](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/)

P.P.S: т.к. лучший ответ уже дан [[@omgwtf](/users/3458/omgwtf)](/users/3458/omgwtf) то я небуду переписывать свой ответ

Comment: всё хорошо, но есть одно но, мне нужно чтоб когда курсор убирался, ссылка становилась прежней и ещё одна просьба если можно, закаментируй пожалусто функции javascripta, просто хочется ещё и разобратся в этом а не просто тупо скопировать и вставить

Comment: Исправил! Теперь все в норме...

Comment: рад что мы друг другу помогли:))

Comment: @Rules и @Рома Прогер, обновил свой ответ. Посмотрите как будет работать у вас. Лично у меня все работает.

Comment: @Рома Прогер , я усовершенствовал свой ответ теперь вы можете задать свойства при :hover перечислив их:

    ul li a.lihover{
      // сдесь
    }

Очень подробно пркомментировал теперь любому надеюсь понятно насколько велик и могуч JavaScript :)

Comment: @Рома Прогер обнаружил что старый код не работал в IE<9 исправил ответ окончательный код идеально работает во всех браузерах! Используйте его!

P.S. Проблема была в том что IE<9 не поддерживает document.getElementsByClassName написал свою кроссбраузерную ф-цию

Comment: Это полный бред для таких целей писать такой скрипт, это можно реализовать через цсс
ul li, ul li a{color:black}
ul li a:hover{color:red}
ul li:hover a{color:red}

Comment: Хм, вы написали слово "реализация" в кавычках, в то время как для банальных цсс вещей используете монструозный js код и какой еще режим совместимости ИЕ, это самый простой цсс код, который прекрасно работает начиная с ие7

Comment: Под словом "реализация я подразумевал ваш подход к решению" и кстати мой код работает так же и в IE>=4 :)

Answer (score 7):

Тут просто задан неправильный селектор. http://jsfiddle.net/DL6z5/

```
ul li:hover
```

Изменяет `li` при наведении.

```
ul li a:hover
```

Изменяет `a` при наведении.

А нужно изменить `a` при наведении на `li`

```
ul li:hover a
```

---

Я бы сделал немного другой css http://jsfiddle.net/bjS8D/1/

```
ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;    
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #000;
    background: #6495ED;
    font-size: 19px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: color .5s ease;
    -o-transition: color .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: color .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: color .5s ease;    
}
ul li a:hover {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #000080;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: @omgwtf вы единственный из всех нас кто основательно снает CSS :) ИМХО

Comment: @omgwtf, omg wtf)))) Согласен вы лучший) Еще и перетекание плавное сделали...)))

Comment: @omgwtf  а где вы учили CSS?

Comment: @Rules книги + много практики

Comment: А какие книги (особенно про -moz- -o- и всякие такие селекторы интересно) можно поинтересоваться?

Comment: Про вендорные префиксы в книгах мало написано (говорится что они есть), о них лучше читать в блогах/dev-блогах разработчиков браузеров. Так же о CSS3 много материала в американских и европейских блогах.

Comment: @Rules попробуйте compass/scss. Be different!

Comment: Спасибо, а то на одном отличном знании html/JS без такого же CSS далеко не уедешь! :)

Answer (score 3):

У вас явно указано, что ссылка всегда должна быть черного цвета. Даже при наведении. Если хотите, чтобы работало, нужно изменяющиеся свойства указывать в родители ul li. Вот... Т.е:

```
<style> 
ul { margin-top:20px; list-style:none; } 
li { color:black; float:left; width:80px; height:30px; line-height:30px; background:#6495ED; text-align:center; margin-left:1px; border-radius:10px 10px 0 0; } 
ul li a { text-decoration:none; font-size:19px; } 
ul li:hover { margin-top:-20px; height:50px; line-height:50px; background:#000080; color:red; font-weight:bold; }  
</style>
```

**UPD:**

Люди, вы не спешите CSS решение так скоро отметать. С первого раза редко что получается))) Сами же знаете:)
Вот. Все проверил.

```
ul { margin-top:20px; list-style:none; } 
li { color:black; float:left; width:80px; height:30px; line-height:30px; background:#6495ED; text-align:center; margin-left:1px; 
     border-radius:10px 10px 0 0; margin-top: 20px;} 
ul li a { text-decoration:none; font-size:19px; color: black; } 
ul li:hover { margin-top:0; height:50px; line-height:50px; background:#000080; color:red; font-weight:bold; }  
ul li:hover a { color:red; font-weight:bold; }
```

`ul li:hover a` - и есть та самая магическая строчка))

Comment: А да вспомнил есть псевдокласс :link который позволяет не насильно заставить ссылку иметь по умолчанию нужные св-ва чтоб потом при указании :hover всё работало т.е:

    ul li a:link { \\ Стиль для a }
    ul li a:hover { \\ Стиль для a с :hover}

Comment: нет это всё не то, hover тем более я уже устанавливал.

ответ 1 от Dobby007 тоже не сработал ссылки просто стали синего цвета

Comment: хорошо, жду ответ

Comment: Протестировал... @Dobby007 ваш код в IE8 работает странно а в IE<8 вообще не работает! Вот почему я люблю JavaScript и DOM  :)

Comment: Поганный IE... Ну ладно... Черт с ним) А где вы так быстро тестируете во всех IE свой код? Программа какая-та?

Comment: У меня IE 9 там есть "Средства разработчика" (хоть какая то польза от IE :) ) там можно выбирать ("Режим браузера" и "Режим документов")

Comment: Это точно)) Хоть какая-та польза))) Теперь буду знать. Жаль IE6 там нет. Но для этого была вроде программа. Называлась IE Tester по-моему... Правда как-то глюковато она работала... Мне показалось...

Comment: @Rules, бебебе))) Теперь все работает во всех IE)))))

Comment: @Dobby специально для того чтобы написать новый комментарий удалил один из старых (на Хэшкоде лимит комментариев)
Так вот: @Dobby, ваш код работает везде кроме IE в "режиме совместимости"! (там при наведении ни на пункт меню не на ссылку ни чего не происходит).
Как окзалось мой старый код тоже не работал в IE<9 (тк IE<9 не поддерживает document.getElementsByClassName()) но я всё исправил теперь МОЙ КОД идеально работает во всех браузерах в том числе в IE в "режиме совместимости"!
Вывод прост: JavaScript rulez! (JavaScript рулит)! (Конечно если попадает в руки к опытному разработчику!)

Comment: Да. Согласен с вами) IE6 hover не поддерживает вроде как. Только на ссылках. Ну попытка не пытка) Вы бы еще сделали так: 

    if(document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) { 
       function getElementsByClassName()....

Встроенная браузерная функция то в любом случае будет работать быстрее..